# Does phishing include ransomware?

Tags: phishing, ransomware, terminology

Does the definition of *phishing* also include tricking the victim into executing malware, such as ransomware, that's **not** used to retrieve the victim's information?

As I see it, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) of phishing does not include ransomware:

> Phishing is the fraudulent attempt to obtain sensitive information or data, such as usernames, passwords and credit card details or other sensitive details, by impersonating oneself as a trustworthy entity in a digital communication.

Contrary, [this guide from SonicWall](https://www.sonicwall.com/resources/ebook/ebook-how-ransomware-can-hold-your-business-hostage/) does include ransomware in the definition of phishing:

> One of the most common distribution methods of ransomware is phishing emails. These types of emails attempt to entice recipients to open an email and click on a website link. The site may ask for sensitive information or contain malware, such as ransomware, that is downloaded onto the victim’s system.

[Proofpoint](https://www.proofpoint.com/sites/default/files/gtd-pfpt-uk-tr-state-of-the-phish-2020-a4_final.pdf), too, includes ransomware infections as part of phishing:

> “Phishing” can mean different things to different people, but we use the term in a general sense. In the context of this report, phishing encompasses all socially engineered emails, regardless of the specific malicious intent (such as directing users to dangerous websites, distributing malware, collecting credentials and so on)

I know about [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173094/why-is-phishing-becoming-synonymous-with-ransomware) discussion, but could it be that there's a specific and a general definition of the concept of *phishing*? Or is there a case for saying that there's **only one** definition (making the specific or the general definition incorrect)?

Comment: Think of the actual act of fishing. It doesn't matter if your bait is real, fake, poisonous, or just an empty hook. Additionally it doesn't matter if your goal is to eat your catch raw, collect eggs, catch and release, cook, tag, throw it ashore to rot, let it swim around indefinitely on the hook, kill, use as bait for another fish, or keep it as a pet. You successfully fish when your target nabs the hook regardless of their motivation nor yours.

Comment: Maybe I’m an old codger here, but in *my* day, an email that tricked you into downloading malware was called a *trojan*. I never seem to hear that term used anymore.

Comment: @WesSayeed Trojan is a kind of malware (malicious software). Email is not a software. Phishing is a social engineering technique - an action/procedure how to do something (not a software or data).

Comment: Broadly, no. "Phishing" is when the blokes in black hats send huge numbers of messages to effectively random addresses and take further action against anyone who replies. "Further action" might include sending you ransom- or any other malware, but that's a different thing.

Comment: I might be re-stating what pabouk said, but I don't think the SonicWall quote "includes ransomware in the definition of phishing". It does, however, mention phishing as a "common distribution method" of ransomware. So phishing is not ransomware, but ransomware could be distributed via phishing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Phishing" is attempting to *catch* something, hence the name. Most often the "something" in question is credentials, but it can be any number of things (money, source code or other secrets, direct access to a computer system via some means that bypasses the normal need for credentials, etc.). Ransomware is, of course, generally an attempt to extort money, but the acquisition of money is rather downstream of the ransomware installation (compared to, e.g., obtaining somebody's payment card or bank info).

Phishing is the most commonly discussed form of online social engineering, and as such, most things that social engineering are used for, if initiated over a computer and especially over email or similar, get termed phishing. (This is similar to the way that approximately all malware gets termed a "virus", even though malware that infects files on the host system to spread copies of itself is actually quite rare now, because software viruses were the well-known example of malware for some years.)

By strict definition, I would say that getting a victim to install ransomware does not count as phishing (a remote-access backdoor would be a more plausible case). However, if I were to ask somebody "how did your network get infected with this ransomware?" and they answered "an admin got phished"... I would have further questions, but I would understand them to be saying "an admin fell for a fraudulent communication, probably an email, and took actions enabling the malware to be installed". It wouldn't be clear whether the attacker had directly gained access to the network or simply tricked the victim into installing the malware, or what (if any) harms or data exposures there might be beyond the ransomware (of course, ransomware can also contain backdoors or other nastiness), but it wouldn't be incomprehensible or totally uninformative.

Whether you want to use this term in your situation probably depends on the audience. Language, of course, shifts over time, and not uniformly across a population. For some people, the strict definition would be what you should always use, and thus you might say something like "Targeted social engineering attack via spoofed email sent to the admin, resulting in the installation of an update package that was actually a Trojan ransomware installer". Or you might just say "spear-phishing attack on the admin linking to the installer". Or something else.

Answer (score 28):

The term you're looking for here is *social engineering*. This is an umbrella term that describes any attempt to get a person to perform a particular action - particularly one that benefits the social engineer over the victim.

Phishing is a specific type of social engineering that is generally used to mean tricking a user into giving away sensitive information, but the terminology is not so rigid that the average security professional would frown upon you using "phishing" to refer to tricking a user into installing ransomware.

Answer (score 5):

Language evolves.

Historically, no, emails with malicious attachments or code were not considered "phishing". [Phishing was about](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/phishing) gathering information from the victim.

But, as with all technology, lines blurred, attack techniques blended, and the desire to clearly communicate won out. Now, all "bad" emails are described as "phishing". I don't think that this evolution has been done mindfully or thoughtfully, but it is how the word is being used right now.

Comment: It kinda makes sense to me that it's evolved that way - the kind of person who is likely able to tell the difference between phishing and other bad emails is not going to click on them and find out which the email was.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, if you're looking for "empirical" definitions, I'd veer away from commercial entities, as their definitions tend to lean in to the products that they sell (Sonicwall, Proofpoint, etc.). The Wikipedia reference is good, and the definition citations look to be linking back to academic papers, but Wikipedia is always going to be a "summary" page, rather than the place to go in-depth.

My current default reference set for this kind of thing is the MITRE ATT&CK framework, as it seems to be about as well-referenced and complete as I've found.

With reference to Phishing, their definition is:

> Adversaries may send victims emails containing malicious attachments or links, typically to **execute malicious code** on victim systems or to gather credentials for use of Valid Accounts. Phishing may also be conducted via third-party services, like social media platforms.

https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1566/

Essentially saying that gathering creds is one line, and executing malware is another.

Comment: But different authoritative bodies define phishing differently from MITRE. That's my point in my answer. There is no "empirical" definition since language evolves.

Comment: In MITRE ATT&CK, phishing is "Initial access". They indeed discuss what it can be used for, but it is the access vector only. "Malware activities" will be in "Execution" and further on. Depending on the case, this can be a semantic, academic discussion, or a way to dispatch efforts.

Answer (score 1):

**Phishing** was coined from word **fishing**, for a specific reason.

Phishing is a sub-set of social engineering attacks
[image]

In particular, phishing's peculiarity is its **bulky** and unpersonalized nature, unlike complex social engineering attacks that involve human interaction and deep knowledge of the (high-profile) victim.

When you go fishing, you'll drop the bait waiting to catch any fish. You don't want a specific fish in the sea.

In this sense, and in accordance to SonicWall, I'd advise that the following **can** be considered phishing

> Identical emails sent to a plethora of recipients, exactly like spam (bulk...), which trick the user into opening a malicious attachment, download a malicious file from a link.

In this sense, I'd advise that the following is **not** phishing as it is a dedicated attack to a high-value target

> Email sent to Purchase Director of ACME LLC by the hacked account of one of the suppliers, saying that there was an error in the last invoice (the alleged invoice can match the supplier's logo) and that they can find attached a new version of invoice with a significantly revised price. The Directory of Purchases is called by name, the sender represents a real employee at the supplier

Comment: Your second example is sometimes referred to as spear-phishing. So you might call it a subcategory of phishing. There is also the term "whaling", for when the target being attacked is high value.

Answer (score -2):

I would use “phishing” for any attack where someone sends you a message that is in itself harmless, as long as you don’t act on it, but works by convincing a human to do things voluntarily that cause the damage.

For example, you might receive an email seemingly from your boss that tells you to send $100,000 to some bank account. That’s phishing, because there’s no damage until you voluntarily send the money. Or you might work in IT and get an email about a security update from a third party site that you need to install - if that “security update” turns out to be ransomware then you fell for a phishing attack resulting in ransomware being installed.

Malicious attachments that cause damage if you open them would not be phishing.